# There is a way to create a JPanel chooser in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

[Im trying to create a layout in java swing that has the possibility to change from some JPanels like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOqfF.png)

How Can i do that thing in java?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html

Comment: [How to Use Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is called a TabbedPane in swing. Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).